# Install Magento 2 PWA

Tags: magento2, setup, pwa-studio, npm

Can Anybody suggest to me the best guide to install the Magento 2 PWA step by step?

I tried many things, but face this issue on using this command :

**yarn buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept**

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept
  ⓧ  error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
  ⓧ  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I have successfully installed the Magento 2 PWA using the below reference link. According to this article, We can install PWA using two approaches. So I am sharing both for your reference which might solve your issue.

**A] Prerequisite for Magento 2 PWA.** [For more details, Check the Magento official website link.](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/tutorials/)

[1] Click Here To Install Or Remove NodeJS >=16 LTS](https://devhooks.in/blog/how-to-install-and-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu)

[2] Click Here To Install Yarn >=1.13.0](https://devhooks.in/blog/magento-pwa-sudio-installation-guide)

**B] Install Magento 2 PWA with complete guide**

[1] Click here for the Latest way to install Magento 2 PWA.](https://devhooks.in/blog/easiest-way-to-install-magento-2-pwa-studio)

[2] Click here for the older way to install Magento 2 PWA.](https://devhooks.in/blog/magento-pwa-sudio-installation-guide)

Comment: When I run this command sudo yarn run buildpack create-custom-origin .
 facing this error:  yarn run v1.22.19
$ buildpack create-custom-origin .
  ⓧ  error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
  ⓧ  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
 I also tried to remove the backed venia and upgrade it. but didn't work

Comment: I also solved the above problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step guide to install the Magento 2 Progressive Web App (PWA) Studio:

System Requirements:

PHP 7.3 or later
MySQL 5.7 or later
Magento 2.3.x
Node.js 14.x
Yarn 1.22.x
Git
Clone the Magento 2 PWA Studio repository:

Open the terminal or command prompt
Run the following command to clone the repository:
git clone https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio.git
Navigate to the pwa-studio directory:

Run the following command:
cd pwa-studio
Install the required dependencies:

Run the following command:
yarn install
Create a new project using the following command:

yarn create @magento/pwa 
Navigate to the project directory:

Run the following command:
cd 
Add Magento 2 as a server:

Run the following command:
yarn run buildpack create-env  
Start the development server:

Run the following command:
yarn run watch
Access the PWA Studio frontend:

Open a web browser and navigate to http://localhost:8080
Test the PWA Studio installation:

Test the installation by making changes to the storefront and verifying that the changes are reflected in the browser.
Note: The above steps are just an overview, for more detailed instructions and troubleshooting guide, refer to the official Magento 2 PWA Studio documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this command.

After that you can run your command if again got error you may need to your command run 2-3 times.

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```