How to get the base URL in Magento 2 PWA?
I am working with Magento 2 PWA (Progressive Web App) and need to retrieve the base URL in my custom components. I understand that in a regular Magento 2 setup, the base URL can be accessed via the following:
$baseUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();

However, since this is a PWA setup, I am unsure how to access the base URL

hello dear i will share some link that is help for you. https://github.com/themagedigest/pwa-installation-magento2/blob/main/Magento%20PWA%20Installation.pdf https://www.mgt-commerce.com/tutorial/how-to-install-pwa-studio-in-magento-2-4/ https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/364309/install-magento-2-pwa
